Spivak calculus on manifolds exercise 5-22
problem screenshot
The problem seems wrong, please tell me what I'm misunderstanding. If $n=1$, $M_1=[0,3]$, $M_2=[1,2]$, $\omega$ can be any scalar field, and $\int_{\partial M_1} \omega = \omega(3) - \omega(0)$ certainly doesn't have to equal $\int_{\partial M_2} \omega = \omega(2) - \omega(1)$.

Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using MathJax) instead of posting links to pictures.

Apparently the essential hypothesis that $\omega$ be closed was omitted.

And even then, the exercise seems somewhat silly because both integrals vanish by Stokes’ theorem, so there’s no need to introduce the $M$. I guess the more general phrasing of the question is to start with two compact hypersurfaces $\Sigma_1,\Sigma_2$ whose union can suitably be interpreted as the boundary of some compact $M$. This would then allow for non-zero but equal fluxes (e.g the famous $d\theta$ and higher dimensional analogues). Can’t believe I missed this typo for so long…

Agreed. I actually had never read the problem before!

Where are you getting this? Agreed with @peek-a-boo, if this is the case it seems silly

Where am I getting what? Years of knowledge. It is meant to be an application of Stokes’s Theorem. I’m sure Spivak was thinking of the Gauss’s Law applications, as peek-a-boo suggested, and he just messed up. Sadly, he’s no longer alive for us to ask him what he was thinking at the time.
